# The quotient of a direct sum of rings

Tags: ring-theory

Is the quotient of a direct sum of rings isomorphic to the direct sum of the quotients?

$$ (R_1 \oplus R_2 ) / \langle (x_1, x_2)\rangle = (R_1 / \langle x_1\rangle ) \oplus (R_2 /\langle x_2\rangle) \text{ ?}$$

Comment: You meant $\langle(x_1,x_2)\rangle$ on the left side?

Comment: Note that $R_1/\langle x_1\rangle$ is standard usage and $R_1/< x_1 >{}$ is not. I changed it. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Consider homomorphism $\phi: (R_1 \oplus R_2 )  \to (R_1 / \langle x_1\rangle ) \oplus (R_2 /\langle x_2\rangle) $ which sends $(a,b)\to (a+\langle x_1\rangle, b+ \langle x_2\rangle)$. Clearly $\phi$ is onto.
Now  the ker$(\phi)=\{(a,b)\ |\ a=r_1x_1, b=r_2x_2\ \text{for some}\ r_1,r_2\in R \}=\langle(x_1,x_2)\rangle$.

And apply First isomorphism theorem for rings.

**NOTE-** This does not hold if $R$ is noncommutative and $\langle x_1 \rangle$ is left ideal and $\langle x_1 \rangle$ is a right ideal, but will hold if both principal ideals are either left or right.

Anyways, it is safe if R is commutative.